# Uniqueness Proof for Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone show me how to prove the uniqueness of (p is prime and q is prime and p-q=3)?

Comment: Hint: $p = q+3$ and adding $3$ to an odd number would give an even number.

Answer (score 2):

p-q = 3 implies that p or q is even. The only even prime is 2. Therefore q = 2, hence the uniqueness.